# Posting data using ruby, json/nancy and C#

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, nancy

I'm working on a financial site and part of the functionality will be transfers between accounts. We initially developed it using Ruby on Rails referencing stored procedures on the database. Due to the need for a mobile app to be developed we have now moved to json/nancy. I am okay with getting data but post is proving more difficult.

Here is the controller code:

```
post :index do
begin

  amount = params[:amount].to_f
  from = @customer.fetch_account(params[:from].to_i)
  to = @customer.fetch_account(params[:to].to_i)

  if from.account_id == to.account_id
    flash[:error]= 'Cannot transfer funds to same account'
  else
    response = post_call('/Accounts/InternalXfer', { 
    :FromAccountID => 42,
    :ToAccountID => 643,
    :ToAccountTypeID => 2,
    :Amount => 200})

    if result.first.empty?
      raise
    end
    r = result.first
    if r.nil?
      raise 
    elsif r['Value'].to_s.eql? 'Error'
      flash[:error] = r['Message'].to_s
    elsif r['Value'].to_s.eql? 'Success'
      flash[:notice] = r['Message'].to_s
    else
      flash[:error] = r.to_s
    end
  end
  rescue
    flash[:error]= 'Something went wrong'
end
  redirect to('/transfers')
end
```

Here is the c# code:

```
namespace CompanyServices.Controllers
{
    public class AccountModule : NancyModule
    {
        public AccountModule() : base("/Accounts")
        {
            #region GET Methods
            Get["/"] = _ =>
            {
                return "Hello Accounts";
            };

            Get["/{customerID}"] = parameters =>
            {
                Customers customerIB = new Customers();

                return customerIB.GetAccounts(parameters.customerID);
            };
            #endregion

            #region PUT Methods
            Post["/InternalXfer"] = parameters =>
            {
                IB_MobileAPI.Models.InternalXferModel xfer = this.Bind<IB_MobileAPI.Models.InternalXferModel>();

                TransferInternal transferInternal = new TransferInternal();

                string ret = transferInternal.IBTransfer(xfer.FromAccountID, xfer.ToAccountID, xfer.ToAccountTypeID, xfer.Amount);

                return ret;
            };
            #endregion
        }
    }
}
```

And finally here is a partial of IBTransfer referenced above:

```
@SavingAccID bigint = 0, 
@TargetAccID bigint = 0, 
@Amount     money = 0

INSERT INTO CUTransaction(
        CUSessionID,
        ReceiptNo,
        ValueDate,
        CUAccountID,
        CUAccountFeeID,
        TransactionSourceID,
        TransactionTypeID, 
        ReversalReceiptNo,
        Credit,
        Amount,
        Balance,
        CurrencyID,
        GLAmount,
        DebitAccID,
        CreditAccID, 
        ProductID) 
    VALUES (
        @CUSessionID,
        @ReceiptNo,
        @ValueDate,
        @SavingAccID,
        null,
        @TransactionSourceID,
        2,      -- Type for WITHDRAWAL
        0,
        0,
        @Amount,
        @Amount, -- CONAIL Temporary - not needed
        @CurrencyID,
        @Amount,
        @GL_SavingsControlID,
        @GL_UserSuspenseID, 
        @SavingProductID)
IF (@@ERROR = 0)
    SELECT @Returned = @@Identity
```

I also included this for debugging:

```
http.set_debug_output $stderr
```

The output of which is:

```
opening connection to 10.10.10.27...
opened
<- "POST /Accounts/InternalXfer HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: Ruby\r\nC                    ontent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: 10.                    10.10.27:7820\r\nContent-Length: 61\r\n\r\n"
<- "FromAccountID=42&ToAccountID=643&ToAccountTypeID=2&Amount=200"
-> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
-> "Cache-Control: private\r\n"
-> "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
-> "Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0\r\n"
-> "X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319\r\n"
-> "X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcZWFtb25ubWNcRG9jdW1lbnRzXFZpc3VhbCBTdHV                    kaW8gMjAxMlxQcm9qZWN0c1xBYmFjdXNfSUJfTW9iaWxlXEFiYWN1c0lCLlNlcnZpY2VzXEFjY291bnR                    zXEludGVybmFsWGZlcg==?=\r\n"
-> "X-Powered-By: ASP.NET\r\n"
-> "Date: Thu, 09 Jul 2015 08:47:41 GMT\r\n"
-> "Connection: close\r\n"
-> "Content-Length: 1\r\n"
-> "\r\n"
reading 1 bytes...
-> "0"
read 1 bytes
Conn close
  DEBUG -  SERVICE - POST (0.0300s) /Accounts/InternalXfer
```

Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong, what I'm missing, or anyway to further debug so I can understand how to make this work.

Comment: What is the actual error you get?

Comment: @Christian Horsdal There doesnt seem to be an error, just that the data isnt being posted to the database. Strangely it works on a colleagues computer so i'm thinking it may be the configuration of my computer. Strange though that GET's are working.